# Changing Only Part of a Custom UITableViewCell Selected Background Color

Tags: uitableview

I have a custom cell that I am controlling the color of when it is selected, ie the example code below:

```
UIView *selectedBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600)];
[selectedBackground setBackgroundColor:[UIColor selectedCellColor]];
self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackground;
```

This works, however I would only like to have part of the cell change colors when selected.  My custom cell is broken down into many different subviews, and I have it sectioned out where I would be able to define the specific view that I would like to change colors for.

How can I control the selectedBackgroundView, or use a different method, to have the background color change encompass a single subview in my cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya you are in the rite way,by subclassing the UITableView cell
hear is the sample code that you may find the answer for your question :)

```
 //in subclassed cell class

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
  {
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 334, 250);
    UILabel *aLabel1= [[UILabel alloc]init];
    UILabel *aLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];


    self.label1 = aLabel1;
    self.label2 = aLabel2;


    self.label1.text = @"Happy";
    self.label2.text = @"coding";




    UIImageView *bg1 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    bg1.tag = 100;

    UIImageView *bg2 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    bg2.tag = 200;

    [self addSubview:bg1]; // you must add your background views first
    [self addSubview:bg2];

    [self addSubview:label1];//then other views
    [self addSubview:label2];

    [aLabel1 release];
    [aLabel2 release];

    [bg1 release];
    [bg2 release];

}
return self;

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   // Configure the view for the selected state

    // hear only you can manage your background views, simply i am adding 2 imageviews by setting different colors 
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
if(selected)
{
    self.label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    UIImageView *bg1 = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:100];
    bg1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,334/2, 250);
    bg1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];


}
else
{
    self.label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    self.label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIImageView *bg2 =(UIImageView *) [self viewWithTag:200];
    bg2.frame =  CGRectMake(35, 0, 334/2, 250);
    bg2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
 }

}

   -(void)layoutSubviews
  {

    //i am setting the frame for each views that i hav added
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.label1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 35);
    self.label2.frame = CGRectMake(65, 10, 60, 35);

 }
```

hope helps u :)
note: i am using "without ARC"

Comment: So I should have been more specific with what I was using and my exact problem. I already implemented a solution like yours, but I later had to add "cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;" to get the results I wanted. I am using ARC and creating my cell subivews using constraints in code, so my answer was different, but had the same basic principles. Thanks for taking the time to help!