# How to change the background color of a potion of a selected custom table view cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, xib, uitableview

Is it possible to programmatically set (from the awakeFromNib method) the background color of a portion of a custom table view cell when the cell is selected.

My attempt so far highlights the entire cell in red

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Comment: may be you can use gradients, rather than a flat red color? 
or create a uiview with the size of the red you want and insert it above the background?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128497/changing-only-part-of-a-custom-uitableviewcell-selected-background-color/18140257#18140257

Answer (score 0):

If this is acceptable, modifying your code a little.

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,200,100); //this could be replaced with numbers to cover portion of your cell
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Comment: I've tried that but the entire cell is highlighted red. Setting the frame doesnt change anything

Comment: Setting view as background will fill the view, rather than setting it as background, can you try insertSubViewAtIndex:1? Dont have a mac right now to test it out.

Comment: The red is added to all the cells. I only want the selected cell to be red. I didnt make this clear in the question. Sorry

Comment: Ah, ok - you can use that code, probably refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color